# Querying Price for a Stock at a Particular Date Time

Tags: google-sheets, google-finance

I can fetch the price of a stock using this:

```
=INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("GOOG","price","12/13/2020"),2,2)
```

However how to I query price at a particular date **and time**. I am open to use anything: GOOGLE, EXCEL etc. etc. I am looking at NSE and BSE exchange.

Comment: Do you know a website where this data exists as a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GOOGLEFINANCE`, and other free sites (e.g Yahoo, etc.) only presents daily data (e.g. Open, High, Low, Close) so it is not an option.

Specific/Timely stock prices as far as I know are not free and you will have to buy that information.

Quoting from this [page](http://quant.caltech.edu/historical-stock-data.html),

> Commercial Historical Data

> Higher resolution and more complete datasets are generally not available for free.

Unless you can provide a site that shows that data, include the site on your post and I'll provide you a formula/script to fetch/scrape that data.

Comment: I have CSV files which contains date and time of a symbol. How do I query that in Google sheets? For eg: this is the data for the 1st of July stored in a folder called '01JUL' and in a file called ACC.txt

ACC,20210701,09:08,2021.80,2021.80,2021.80,2021.80,465,0

Comment: Hi @CuriousDev, you might need to post it as another question as that is unrelated to the original question here. But to give you idea, I do think that if the file is not in google drive or not accessible online, then it would be impossible to import that data automatically (via formula or script) to sheets.

Comment: Oh I can add these files to a google drive, no problem. Here's my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68659608/how-do-i-query-a-bunch-of-csv-files-in-google-sheets

Comment: Did you get the chance to check my question?